# Matlab "if array" functionality

Tags: arrays, matlab, if-statement

Just stumbled across a bug in some old code of mine where to check if an array was empty or not I just wrote:

```
if my_array
...(do stuff)
end
```

instead of using isempty or something like that.

What I have discovered is that "if my_array" returns 0 only if the array is indeed empty OR if one or more of the components in the array are 0.

Is this expected? What exactly is going on? Is matlab performing an and operation on all the elements?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is exactly the behaviour as it is [documented](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html):

> An evaluated expression is true when the result is nonempty
>   and contains all nonzero elements (logical or real numeric). Otherwise,
>   the expression is false.

Comment: ! Thank you, I feel a bit of a fool for not seeing this, I had checked the docs. Interestingly omitting the isempty gives roughly a 25% speedup. I shall be sad to lose that!